# merge two array with the same key and value

Tags: php, arrays

I have arrays of $array_one:

```
print_r($array_one);
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [myid] => 653509
            [date] => 2015-03-15 00:07:03
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [myid] => 653511
            [date] => Never
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [myid] => 653530
            [date] => 2015-03-15 02:06:26
        )
```

And then the arrays of $array_two;

```
print_r($array_two);

Array
(

    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [myid] => 653530
            [pin] => 12fdg34345
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [myid] => 653509
            [pin] => 1we2534dgf5
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [myid] => 653511
            [pin] => 12wer3u45
        )
```

and then I want to merge it based on the keys with the same value, in which the expected result would be:

```
Array
(

    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [myid] => 653530
            [pin] => 12fdg34345
            [date] => 2015-03-15 02:06:26
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [myid] => 653509
            [pin] => 1we2534dgf5
            [date] => 2015-03-15 00:07:03
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [myid] => 653511
            [pin] => 12wer3u45
            [date] => Never
        )
```

from the result above, the array key of `date` from the first_array is push to 
the second_array based on the similar value of the key of `my_id`.

Is there a way to do this?

Please help and many thanks for the help.

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: No, I don't have any idea about this. I am googling but no relevant issue found

Comment: I have tried array_merge and array_combine but it doesn't work

Comment: ^ Ah see you *tried* something. Add your attempt(s) into your questions and show where you are stuck.

Comment: And what I have tried is so messy

Comment: this is what I have tried `$array3 = array_merge($array_one, $array_two);` but when I print the `$array3` each array are still separated.

Comment: Doesn't matter, who cares :) We then can see better where you got stuck and where you need help

Comment: just loop both of those with foreach, no need to use any function

Comment: Where are the values coming from? Can you read the data in such a way that the current Object entries are associative arrays?

Comment: @Stephen both of the array are stdClass Object. I am not sure about them are associative arrays. How to read that? thanks.

Comment: Yes I realise they're both stdClass objects right now. Where is the data coming from (e.g. DB, JSOS files, generated at runtime, etc?) - if they are associative arrays rather than stdClass objects, what you want can be achived with a couple of built-in function calls.

Comment: @Stephen they both are coming from database

Comment: Ok, I will post an answer with how it can be achieved, with a note about them being arrays rather than objects.

Comment: I have no luck with that: the result is `Array()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77601/discussion-between-stephen-and-iyal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, **this solution depends on the structure changing very slightly**, to be arrays of associative arrays, not arrays of objects. As you said the data is coming from (a) database(s), if you're using something like PDO, this should just mean a small change to set the correct fetch mode.

The result can be achieved by combining the php built-in functions `array_column` and `array_replace_recursive`. If you want the resulting array to still be 0-indexed, we can use `array_values` too.

```
$array_one = [
    [
        'myid' => 653509,
        'date' => '2015-03-15 00:07:03'
    ],
    [
        'myid' => 653511,
        'date' => 'Never'
    ],
    [
        'myid' => 653530,
        'date' => '2015-03-15 02:06:26'
    ]
];

$array_two = [
    [
        'myid' => 653530,
        'pin' => '12fdg34345'
    ],
    [
        'myid' => 653509,
        'pin' => '1we2534dgf5'
    ],
    [
        'myid' => 653511,
        'pin' => '12wer3u45'
    ]
];

$merged = array_replace_recursive(
    array_column($array_one, null, 'myid'),
    array_column($array_two, null, 'myid')
);
```

Comment: @iyal did you make sure the inputs are arrays of arrays, not arrays of objects? array_column won't read properties from objects.

Comment: the output of arrays are exactly the same as I copied in my question, and are different from your answer above, Stephen.

Comment: @iyal as I said in my comment and in my answer - this solution **depends** on an array of arrays, not an array of objects.

Comment: I am sorry. the output of $merge is only printed one of the arrays. If I put the array_one in the first line, it prints only the array_one, and vice-versa.

Comment: something is still wrong with the input then. it might be easer to discuss this in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77602/discussion-between-iyal-and-stephen).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $temp_arr_one = array();
    foreach($array_one as $key1=>$val1){
        $temp_arr_one[$val1['myid']] = $val1->date;
    }

    $final_arr = array();

    foreach($array_two as $key2=>$val2){
        $final_arr[$key2]['myid'] = $val2->myid;
        $final_arr[$key2]['pin'] = $val2->pin;
        $final_arr[$key2]['date'] = $temp_arr_one[$val2->myid];
    }

    print_r($final_arr);
?>
```

Comment: I think ( -> )Operator is required

Comment: Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in `$temp_arr_one[$val1['myid']] = $val1->date;`